# Не могу запустить Агент SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

мне надо совершать автоматические задания по графику в SQL Server 2017, но служба агента SQL Server не хочет запускаться, выводя мне это предупреждение [image: введите сюда описание изображения] попыталась в менеджере конфигурации запустить агент, но опять же без результатов[image: введите сюда описание изображения] обновляла Express версию на Developer версию SQL SERVER. Как мне всё таки запустить службу? Или в чём у меня проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут было легче запустить установщик sql servera и сделать repair всех служб